# How do I migrate docker container from one machine to another machine?

Tags: docker

Say I am running a Docker container on my personal computer, I want to migrate that container to my friend machine. The problem here is - the container is running an infinite loop program, I don’t want to kill that program. Instead, I want to pause the container, zip the container then send to my friend system.

This is possible using a virtual machine. Pause the virtual machine, zip the files and then ship to where ever you want. How to do the same in Docker?

Please correct me if I am wrong - I think it is possible to pause a docker container and then move that container to another machine. If so, please tell me how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite possible. Pause current container,  export image with `docker export container_id -o my_container.tar` (this is possible with paused instance) to a TAR-file. , copy the file, import it with `docker import containerid -o my_container.tar` then just start a new container with `docker run` on new machine. You can get container id with `docker ps`.

Comment: @RicardoBranco It will export current instance, that is what required.

Comment: It's not as straightforward as the OP expects.  I have created a script to load / save the volumes before & after import / export.
https://github.com/ricardobranco777/docker-volumes.sh